# Styling CSV files. Wide columns

Tags: php, csv

how do i style my csv file? because when i download it, the spacing is the same and it's not very appealing. how do i make the columns wide and how do i style the headers?

here are my csv codes.

```
<?php


header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=inventory_template.csv');


$output = fopen('php://output', 'w');


fputcsv($output, array('prod_brand', 'prod_name', 'prod_category', 'prod_price', 'prod_desc', 'prod_quantity'));


?>
```

thank you.

Comment: Create xls file instead of CSV if you want to format file. Because CSV means COMMA SEPARATED VALUE

Comment: @Harry I need to reupload it to the database, will xls work?

Comment: If you want to upload into the database then what is the need well format style ? database understand this file easily no need to format

Comment: It's for the user who will use it. hehe. users are picky.

Comment: Read below answer of @jimDini so you have better idea what is the use of CSV

Answer (score 8, accepted):

CSV is created to be a computer-readable format, not human-readable (humans can read it, but there was no intention to make this a pleasurable experience). And it is a very simple format. There are no means to style anything

Comment: I see. Thank you. But is there any other solution to my problem? because the user can download the template, and edit it then reupload it. i've created a function that does that.

Comment: you can probably implement a UI for editing tabular data. it can be nicely styled, etc. but it won't be directly related to CSV format. this UI will just produce CSV after all editing is done. in this scenario you would be hiding the CSV file from direct interaction with user. anyway, this sounds a bit like a solution for a wrong problem. if you need to edit data in database, then your task is creating (or using some readily available) UI for editing data in database and there is no need to think about CSV at all